# Dictionary sorting in python

Tags: python, dictionary

What is the principle of sorting is used in Python?

```
>>> dict = {'a':'paul', 'b':'max', 'c':'bill'}
>>> dict
{'a': 'paul', 'c': 'bill', 'b': 'max'}
```

Why not?

```
{'a': 'paul', 'b': 'max', 'c': 'bill'}
```

Comment: because dictionaries are not sorted. theoretically, the output may be in any order. in your case, it's supposedly in mid-order

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dictionaries](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) in python are unordered collections:

> It is best to think of a dictionary as an unordered set of key: value
>   pairs, with the requirement that the keys are unique (within one
>   dictionary).

Though, you can have an ordered dictionary by using [collections.OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

Comment: Note that "ordered" is distinct from "sorted" though. OrderedDict maintains insertion order, it doesn't sort anything.